dj-rest-auth RegisterView interfering with my signal and preventing it from updating user model
I want to update my custom user model after a user verifies their email using a signal but it does not work and the Django DEBUG page throws a NoReverseMatch error
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(email_confirmed)
def email_confirmed_(request, email_address, **kwargs):
    user = email_address.user
    user.is_active = True

    user.save()

This is my signal code.
The is_active field is set to False by default and should only become True upon the user verifying their account. After adding this signal it doesn't change the is_active field of a verified user to True and I get this error:
(NoReverseMatch at /api/users/registration/
Reverse for 'account_inactive' not found. 'account_inactive' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)
Image here
The problem seems to be coming from the dj-rest-auth RegisterView but I can't seem to understand why and don't know how to fix it.
